# no match for operator[] error

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I've been experimenting with operating overloading in C++ and I tried using templates. But I got this error: *error: no match for 'operator[]' in 'a[4]'*
Here's my code:

```
#include "JSE.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct obj{
    int l;
    template<typename varname>
    varname operator[] (int n){
        return (this->l)+n;
    }
};

int main(void){
    obj a;
    a.l=20;
    cout<<a[4];
    return 0;
}
```

And I only get this error if I use templates. For example, this code works:

```
#include "JSE.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct obj{
    int l;
    int operator[] (int n){
        return (this->l)+n;
    }
};

int main(void){
    obj a;
    a.l=20;
    cout<<a[4];
    return 0;
}
```

What's causing the error and how can I fix it?
Note: I really want to keep the template as I will use it with the operator overloading in a future project.

Comment: how is your `operator[]` supposed to deduce `varname` ?

Comment: I don't see any difference between your two code snippets.

Comment: Could you point out the difference between the two code samples?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to add 2 objects that are always of type 'int' and you want the result to be casted to other types with operator[]?

Comment: Also, you should not really change the semantics of the operators. Your `operator[]` does not behave as it's expected to behave. If you have changed the semantics, how would anyone else be able to understand what's happening when reading your code? How would you-self understand it in a couple of months when you forgot about it?

Comment: The datatype is easily deduced by the fact that the return value is always an int+int.

Comment: @CarlOscarAndersson you are probably referring to the C++14 `auto` feature, or at least C++11 trailing return type with decltype specifier. Now, you would need to call it `a.operator[]<int>(4)`

Comment: This is just an exercise to gain better understanding of the operator overloading. It is really dumb to use the [] operator like this, yet the purpose of the program is to give me a better understanding of the language.

Comment: Yes, auto is what I've been thinking of at the beginning, but Code::Blocks 13.12's g++ compiler doesn't support auto return type functions

Comment: @CarlOscarAndersson Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. you can upgrade your compiler's version that supports C++11/C++14

Comment: @CarlOscarAndersson If the return value is *always* int+int, then why would you need to template the return value?
Obviously, the deduced type should always be int, no matter what.

Comment: Also, as @PiotrS. said, if you don't use the template's type as the operator's argument, the syntax for templated overloaded operators make operator overloading useless.

Comment: C++11: `auto operator[](int n) -> decltype((this->l)+n) { return (this->l)+n; }`, C++14: `auto operator[](int n) { return (this->l)+n; }`

Comment: @PiotrS, I know what Code::Blocks is, That 's after the version indicates a possessive (the g++ compiler of Code::Blocks)

Comment: @KABoissonneault, true, but I wanted to experiment with the templates and overloaded operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for the first program the compiler is unable to determine the return type of the operator.

You could call the operator only like

```
obj a;
a.l=20;
std::cout<< a.operator []<int>( 4 ) << std::endl;
```

Change the class definition the following way

```
template<typename varname>

struct obj{
    varname l;
    varname operator[] (int n){
        return (this->l)+n;
    }
};
```

And in main there will be code like

```
obj<int> a;
a.l=20;
cout<<a[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for template deduction to work the compiler must be able to somehow deduce what the types are that you are using.

```
template<typename varname>
varname operator[] (int n){
    return (this->l)+n;
}
```

Does not allow this as the only thing that you are templating is the return type.  The compiler has no way of know what type you want as a return type and so you are getting error like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d5ef3c53d754c03).

If you instead use the template type in the function parameter then the compiler can deduce the template type as it can use the type passed to the function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct obj{
    int l;
    template<typename varname>
    varname operator[] (varname n){
        return (this->l)+n;
    }
};

int main(void){
    obj a;
    a.l=20;
    cout<<a[4];
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70a09bb002da3ff2)

Comment: Shouldn't it deduce it from the fact that the result is always int+int?

Comment: @CarlOscarAndersson Why would you use templates then ?